# Future Value of Annuity Formula Not Working

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, formula

This is what I have so far:

```
P_s= input("Enter Periodic Payment>")
r_s = input("Rate per Period (Enter as a decimal please)> ")
t_s = input("Number of Periods>")

# Using len() and conditionals to check inputs
if len(P_s) == 0 or len(P_s) > 4:
    print("Must enter a number between 1 and 4 characters for Periodic Payment, please try again")
    exit(0)

if float(r_s) == 0.00 or float(r_s) > 1.00:
  print("Must enter a number between 0.01 and 1.00 for Rate per Period, please try again")
  exit(0)

if len(t_s) == 0 or len(t_s) > 2:
  print("Must enter a number between 1 and 2 characters for Number of Periods, please try again")
  exit(0)

# Check for Raw Input for Valid Characters 
if P_s[0] not in ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',] :
  print("Not in list")
else:
  print("Continue")
  exit()
```

with the check for raw input section the P_s says invalid character in identifier.
Anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your problem, but it could be that extra comma in the list: "'9'**,**]"

Comment: Thanks I tried that but unfortunately, the error is still there.

Comment: I ran your code, and it worked for me. I didn't get any errors, and it printed "Continue"